# How to make website pages accessed by code

Tags: php, html

It's pretty hard to explain so if somebody have a better title then be my guest..

Basically I made a website with 5 pages.

```
1) index.html
2) page.html
3) footer.html
4) menu.html
5) contact.html
```

In order to access the pages you have to type the page name at the end of the domain (I bet you knew that..)

```
I wanted to access the pages with a code..
for example -> mywebsite.com\?page=contact
```

How can I do this ?

Kind Regards,
Kobi.

Comment: try using `.htaccess` file making redirections as you need.. see for htaccess tutorials

Comment: But as I know, .htaccess eventually show you the page name instead of the code as I want, Do you have a tutorial/or what exact thing im looking in the htaccess ... is it 301 ?

Comment: Try methods suggested here https://simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-query-string-redirects/

Answer (score 1):

why don't make a `index.php` with following code:

```
<?php
  include($_GET['page'].'.html');
?>
```

The result will be:

- calling  `mywebsite.com/?page=contact` will open `mywebsite.com/index.php?page=contact` because this is default
- the url will stay `mywebsite.com/?page=contact`
- the script load the file `contact.html` and show it

Comment: Of course first make sure the GET parameter is within allowed bounds, right??

Comment: Of course :) And you can add a nice fallback/error page if not

Answer (score 1):

You only need to configure whatever web server you have to look for a file called `index.php` whenever you don't specify any. That has been a pretty standard feature of all web servers since the early 1990s. In Apache you'll use the [DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) directive; this is what mine looks like:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>
```

Then, write PHP code in such `index.php` to act as router. You should check [Variables From External Sources](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php) and learn about `$_GET`.

However, that's probably not the best layout. Friendly URLs have been around for years:

```
http://example.com/contact
```

... and it's again mostly a web server feature. In Apache you'd use the [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html) module. Here's a sample rule used by some PHP frameworks:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Requested path can be parsed out of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

---

Once you put your hands in the `index.php` file there're a lot of design patterns you can use (modern frameworks often use a third-party [router](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute) and [template engine](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/)) but if you're to learn from scratch and just want to get something done quickly from static HTML you can use a combination of [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statements (to create a route white list) and [readfile()](http://php.net/readfile) to inject each file into the output. (Beware that PHP [include](http://php.net/include) construct family will handle files as PHP code, which is not what you want.)

```
<?php
define('INC_PATH', __DIR__ . '/../wherever/includes/are');

switch ($_GET['page']) {
    case 'contact':
    case 'help':
    case 'whatever':
        $page = $_GET['page'];
        break;
    default:
        $page = 'error';
}
readfile(INC_PATH . '/index.html');
readfile(INC_PATH . '/page.html');
readfile(INC_PATH . '/footer.html');
readfile(INC_PATH . '/menu.html');
readfile(INC_PATH . "/$page.html");
```